# Can I Create a Linked Duplicate Consisting of Only Those Mesh Parts Defined by a Vertex Group Owned by the Duplicated Object?

Tags: mesh, objects, vertex-groups, linked-data

I have made this mesh...

[image]

... and I have create two vertex groups. One for the whole mesh, called  "Start"...

[image]

... and another one which excludes a part of it, called "End".

[image]

How can I duplicate this object as linked, but make it look as it is with the second vertex group ("End"). Meaning, with the last part excluded. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "Duplicate Linked" the object with <kbd>Alt+D</kbd>.

Then, on the duplicate, add a Mask modifier, and select the Vertex Group you want to **keep**.

(You can also select the vertex group you want to **hide**, if you tick "Invert" (double arrow icon) next to the Vertex group field)

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much, I'll need this way too!!! But, is there any other way to do that, so as not to add extra vertices, edges, faces etc? Like when I just duplicate the object as linked.

Comment: If you duplicate As Linked (Alt+D), the mesh will be shared between the two objects so, no. If you do a simple duplicate (Shift+D), then you just need to delete the vertices you don't want.

Comment: Pity... It could be really useful if we could have one mesh and then duplicate it's vertex groups as linked without to add extra vertices, edges, faces etc to project!!! Is there any place-forum I can talk about it? As suggestion...

Comment: Well, the whole point of linked duplicate is to keep the exact same mesh, it's a design decision... Design can be discussed on RightClickSelect : https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Also, it's worth knowing than a Linked Duplicate don't use more memory (BECAUSE it's the exact same mesh). So my answer is still quite efficient in term of memory usage and disk usage. However, it could be a little bit slower to display and render, because of the (small) extra calculations required by the modifier.

Comment: While this works, it's worth noting that linked duplicates don't respect lattice deformations. I don't know why. I imagine a lattice's tweaks do not reference the mesh data node directly. Whether this is a limitation or a strength of lattices I guess depends on one's perspective. But at the very least, one should be aware of this issue. Also, to be clear, i'm not criticizing the answer. I realize that this issue has nothing to do with the proposed solution. It would be just as evident in any other case of putting a lattice on a linked object, while not putting on its duplicate.

Comment: Also, lattices on linked objects cannot be applied. The option is grayed out. This is a curious outcome, and I've never seen anything like it elsewhere. It seems applying the lattice should work even in the case of linked duplicates, since there is only one mesh data node in use between the two objects. One wonders why there would be any kind of conflict that would prevent the applying of the modifier. Might be a bug.

Comment: Modifiers (including Lattices) are linked to the Object, not the Mesh. I understand that it is sometimes frustrating, and can seems unclear - but it's an intended behavior, not a bug. Anyway, the comments are not the place for this kind of extended discussion ;)